# XOM and getChildElements

Tags: java, xml, xom

I use this piece of Java with the XOM library to parse a sitemap.

```
Element root = doc.getRootElement();
Elements urls = root.getChildElements("url");
```

When I'm debugging, I can see that `root` has a whole bunch of children, both `url` elements and text elements. However, `root.getChildElements("url")` returns an empty list.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just realized that the sitemap I'm parsing uses a default namespace, which is "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9".

Changing the code to `root.getChildElements("url", "http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9")` gives me the right result.